# How to separate a string into multiple lines based on a separator but not if it is preceded by '?'

Tags: java, string, replace

I am trying to separate a string into multiple lines based on separator `'` but if there's a `?` character before `'` I want the data to remain in the same line.

Initial String:

> HJK'ABCP?'QR2'SER'

I am able to print the lines like:

> HJK'
>   ABCP?'
>   QR2'
>   SER'

But I want the output as:

> HJK'
>   ABCP?'QR2'
>   SER'

Comment: show your code as base to solve your problem

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: string1.split("(?')"); try to use split function

Comment: @DipakThoke : No. Your regex isn't valid. You need to escape ? with \\. And it doesn't answer the question either.

Comment: Your split doesn't work, and if it did, it would do exactly what shefali doesn't want.

Answer (score 0):

You need a negative lookbehind (http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) :

```
String str = "HJK'ABCP?'QR2'SER'";
System.out.println(str);
System.out.println("---------------");
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("'", "'\r\n"));
System.out.println("---------------");
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("(?<!\\?)'", "'\r\n"));
```

It returns :

```
HJK'ABCP?'QR2'SER'
---------------
HJK'
ABCP?'
QR2'
SER'

---------------
HJK'
ABCP?'QR2'
SER'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex `(?<!\?)'` in split funtion

Answer (score 0):

```
String s="HJK'ABCP?'QR2'SER'";

        System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?<!\\?)'","\r\n"));
```

Comment: You should replace with "'\r\n". ' are missing otherwise